# SSCrypto and PHP

Tags: php, cocoa, openssl, key, rsa

I'm using OpenSSL for registration stuff and I need to generate a license key from my server using RSA. The problem is that SSCrypto and PHP generate different digests. I  tried everything. I'm very desperate. I Googled a lot. Spent more than 3 hours trying to solve it, but nothing seems to solve the problem. Could anyone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Php can execute commands via use of graves or the execute command. Also, capitalize SSL, it looks like you're saying SSI.

Comment: Sorry for the "SSl". Thanks for the tip. I will try to figure something out.

Answer (score 1):

You should try posting a sample digest generated by SSCrypto and by PHP.  My guess would be that the digests are compatible with one another - that SSCrypto can verify digests created by PHP and vice versa - and that you're just not understanding how a PKCS#1 compliant digest works.  See, for example, this:

http://www.frostjedi.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?p=120212#p120212

Also, I'd recommend using [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  It's easier to get support for, it supports naked RSA public keys (eg. RSA keys not encapsulated by a X.509 cert), is easier to use, etc.